# how to show piechart with grey colour circle instead of empty when data is null in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a chartWidget with the use of fl_chart package,

if chart's data is empty its showing empty...but

I want it to show **grey circle with the same size** when chart's data is empty...like my attached image

here is my chart widget

```
class ChartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> mapdata;

  const ChartWidget({super.key, required this.mapdata});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: PieChart(
            PieChartData(
                sectionsSpace: 4,
                centerSpaceRadius: 50,
                sections: mapdata.entries
                    .map((e) => PieChartSectionData(
                    title: e.key.toString(), value: (e.value)))
                    .toList()))
    );
  }

}
```

homescreen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  Map<String,dynamic> expenseData={
    'Food':3000.0,
    'Medicine':4000.0,
    'Others':800.0
  };
  Map<String,dynamic> incomeData={};//here income data is empty

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
        Expanded(child: ChartWidget(mapdata: expenseData,)),
        Expanded(child: ChartWidget(mapdata: incomeData,)),
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sections: mapdata.isEmpty
                  ? [PieChartSectionData(color: Colors.grey)]
                  : mapdata.entries
                      .map((e) => PieChartSectionData(
                          title: e.key.toString(), value: (e.value)))
                      .toList(),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Done.....one more favour....I want to display percentage instead of category title..here.I am providing amount not percentage, and don't want to calculate percentage manually...it draws based on percentage that means it calculates its own. how to know in which property it stores

Comment: I think you need calculate it manually, I read its docs but couldn't find any things.

Comment: ohh ok...in it's section , percentage are not required..it calculate its own..so I thought there can be a way to access it

Comment: If you look at its docs you will see how calculate the share of each section, but it doesn't save or return in any parts.

Comment: I recommended use [pie_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart), it has the option that you want.